# TRIMming shared partition in dual-boot on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, trim

In a couple of days, I'm going to buy a new notebook (Asus N551, should it matter), tending to replace the HDD with a Samsung EVO 500GB SSD. I'll set it up in a dual-boot configuration of Windows 8/Ubuntu Trusty. In my workflow, I need to access some data from both OS, so I'm going to create an additional shared partition (NTFS of course), as I did on my current box. Could this situation bear a risk concerning TRIM, i.e. both systems trying to TRIM the partition, causing corruption? And if so, which system should be handling that particular partition? I read that until recently, Ubuntu just couldn't TRIM NTFS partitions, but apparently, that functionality was added some time ago...

Thanks in advance, haemi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently all Samsung SSDs are blacklisted in the Linux kernel as TRIM used to corrupt the sectors on those SSDs. they are working on this issue with Samsung, though.
Right now Linuxers should maybe consider buying Intel SSDs instead, as they work flawlessly (atleast they aren't blacklisted). For details just look it up in the git repo.

Comment: Thanks for the hint; I've been doing some research now and - as I understand it - the problem has been fixed with a kernel blacklist (for the purposes  of consumers). Apparently, the blacklist forces fstrim to use "standard" TRIM instead of queued TRIM. Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fstrim/+bug/1449005, especially from post #27 onwards. Can you confirm this conclusion?

Comment: Yep, they blacklisted those SSDs for queued TRIM - but they said that they try to work on it, for reenabling this later, when SAMSUNG fixed it.

Comment: Alright, thanks again for your help! Closing question now.